# When to use a list vs a div with flexbox

Tags: html, flexbox, html-lists, semantics

Take a look at this image:

[image: Footer]

Which ones of these would you put in a list tag and why?

[image: Lists]

And what should I think about to decide if I should wrap stuff in a list element? I know there are semantical differences between the two, but sometimes it's hard for me to tell whether something is a list or not when it comes to flex items. And **I don't care about performance** because it probably will be only less than a milisecond difference or something.

Comment: In your title you're asking for the difference between a div and list. In your question you're asking about the difference between an ordered list and an unordered  list. Which is it?

Comment: Also, if you simply look up the definitions of `ul`, `ol` and `div`, you'll read about the differences. Try MDN, their definitions are generally pretty good.

Comment: @Michael_B I meant whether to use a list element (so `<ul>` or `<ol>`) or a `<div>`; basically by saying "`<ul>` or `<ol>`" I meant "list tag"

Comment: @Michael_B the definitions don't tell me much, they just say something like: "this is an unordered / ordered list" but what I'd like to know is when a flex container can be called a proper list and when is it just a meaningless container like a `<div>`